# using mean value theorem to approximate a curve?

Tags: taylor-expansion

If I know $f(a)$, $f'(a)$, $f''(a)$ and so on. I can conclude easily $f(x)$ is approximately $f(a) + (x - a) f'(a)$, but how do I further use $f''(a)$ to calculate a better approximation of the curve?
I can't seem to find a way to use the second derivative.

Yes I know Taylor's series, but the question is how do I get that using the mean value theorem?
Most importantly I want to learn how to apply the mean value theorem, and use it in this situation.

Comment: Do you know Taylor expansions ? Around $x=a$, $f(x)=f(a)+(x-a) f'(a)+\frac{1}{2} (x-a)^2 f''(a)+O\left((x-a)^3\right)$

Comment: Mean value theorem will only give you a certain degree of approximation. There is no better measure than the Taylor series for a function value.

Comment: @Claude L then how do i intuitively get that?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1267295/quadratic-cubic-etc-approximations-without-the-taylor-series or http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/122766/where-do-the-higher-order-terms-in-taylor-series-come-from?rq=1